Upserting into Pinecone Index
I'm trying to upsert some data from a list into a Pinecone index with the following code:
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

def generate_embeddings(text):
    inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).squeeze().detach().numpy()
    return embeddings

embeddings = [generate_embeddings(article) for article in article_content]


pc = Pinecone(api_key="API_KEY")
pc.create_index(
    name="index-name",
    dimension=4096, # Replace with your model dimensions
    metric="cosine", # Replace with your model metric
    spec=ServerlessSpec(
        cloud="aws",
        region="us-east-1"
    ) 
)
index = pc.Index("index-name")

index.upsert(embeddings)


but I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\tvish\llama api.py", line 158, in <module>
    index.upsert(embeddings)
  File "C:\Users\tvish\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pinecone\utils\error_handling.py", line 11, in inner_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tvish\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pinecone\data\index.py", line 175, in upsert
    return self._upsert_batch(vectors, namespace, _check_type, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tvish\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pinecone\data\index.py", line 206, in _upsert_batch
    vectors=list(map(vec_builder, vectors)),
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tvish\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pinecone\data\index.py", line 202, in <lambda>
    vec_builder = lambda v: VectorFactory.build(v, check_type=_check_type)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tvish\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pinecone\data\vector_factory.py", line 30, in build
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid vector value passed: cannot interpret type {type(item)}")
ValueError: Invalid vector value passed: cannot interpret type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>


This is my first time working with vectors and most of this code is stuff I just found online. Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Your embeddings are in a numpy array object, rather than a list of floats as is required by the Pinecone upsert method. Try using .tolist() on the array to convert it to a list of floats.
